# Wordpress posts for multiple years

Tags: wp-query

Trying to get posts from a **specific category** for **specific years**. Nothing is working, including this:

```
<?php $args=array(
'cat' => '11', //Category I'm targeting
'year' => 2008,2009,2010 //Years I want
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

That code will only display posts for 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a date range instead by filtering posts_where:

```
function wpse_43397_where($where=''){
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2008-01-01' AND post_date < '2010-12-31'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'wpse_43397_where');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'wpse_43397_where');
```

Comment: +1 exact same answer, just 34 seconds quicker :D

Comment: @StephenHarris haha I noticed that. +1 to you as well. :)

Comment: But you both forgot that this question was about getting posts from a specific category. ;)

Comment: Not true, use the query you had created already. You can still pass $args to your WP_Query object

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) API:

> Note: The queries above return posts for a specific date period in history, i.e. "Posts from X year, X month, X day". They are unable to fetch posts from a timespan relative to the present, so queries like "Posts from the last 30 days" or "Posts from the last year" are not possible with a basic query, and require use of the posts_where filter to be completed. The examples below use the posts_where filter, and should be modifyable for most time-relative queries.

So you will need to add a custom filter before your query, perform the query and then remove the query again  (so it doesn't effect other queries).

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function my_restrict_to_years( $where = '' ) {
    // posts  in years 2008-2010 
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2008-01-01' AND post_date <= '2010-12-31'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_restrict_to_years' );
$args=array(
 'cat' => '11', //Category I'm targeting
 );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_restrict_to_years' );
```

*Not tested*

Comment: What about the category? How do I add that as part of the filter?

Comment: Just replace $query_string with your `$args`, leaving out the year part.